# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'call'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I got an error.( 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'call' )
I've searched about this error. but I couldn't find the solution I want.

the Error Location: ~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min-1.11.1.js

How can I solve this problem?

**_Layout.vbhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
<meta name="Author" content="" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="" />
<meta name="Description" content="" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min-1.11.1.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js")"></script>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/klis")

@Styles.Render("~/content/kendo")
@Styles.Render("~/content/klis")

</head>
```

**BundleConfig.vb**

```
Public Shared Sub RegisterBundles(ByVal bundles As BundleCollection)

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
               "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"))

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"))

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"))

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/klis").Include("~/klis/js/ks.*"))

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
                "~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/cultures/kendo.culture.ko-KR.min.js"))

    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"))


    bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/content/kendo").Include(
               "~/Content/kendo.common.min.css", "~/Content/kendo.dataviz.min.css", "~/Content/kendo.default.min.css"))

    bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/content/klis").Include("~/klis/css/kendo/ks.*", "~/klis/css/ks.*",
                                              "~/klis/css/control/ks.*", "~/klis/css/site/ks.*", "~/klis/css/page/ks.*",
                                              "~/klis/css/view/ks.*", "~/klis/css/item/ks.*"))

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a very old version of jQuery.  The current version is 3.0, why are you using version 1.11.1?  Is it to just match the version number with jquery-ui ?  These version numbers are not related....

If you update jquery to the latest version this should fix it.

Comment: Humm... Thank u so much, @utxin ( :

Comment: Yapp!! Thank u ~ ( :